# how to access specific team site in share-point using rest apis

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

**goal:** I'm trying to access a specific team site which created in my share-point account using REST APIs and create a folder inside there (Documents folder - default location)

**actual results:** I'm getting 403 error code. following is the response body which I'm getting.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
        }
    }
}
```

**expected result:** specified folder should be created and response code should be 201 or 200

**what I've tried:**

1. first registered the app in both share-point as well as Azure
2. get the bearer token calling share-point rest api
3. tested get apis for share-point and all are worked as expected.
4. before each request I set the bearer token in the request header
5. following are the other request headers which I'm setting

```
Content-Type : application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest : some random string
Accept : application/json;odata=verbose
```

---

following is the share-point REST API, I used POST method for creating a folder

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite_ForB/_api/web/folders
```

following is the request body which I'm sending

```
{ 
    "__metadata":{ 
        "type":"SP.Folder"
    },
    "ServerRelativeUrl":"/Shared Documents/buddhika-test-folder-03"
}
```

---

In the share-point documentation site they've provided the API format.
I tried with that format , but couldn't get the result as well.

following is from share-point documentation.

> To access a specific site, use the following construction:

```
http://server/site/_api/web
```

in that case I have tried as following

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/TeamSite_ForB/_api/web/folders
```

I'm getting response as 404 Not found with no response message.

I have searched through many documents but couldn't find how to access a specific team site.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The request REST API URL as below.

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite_ForB/_api/web/folders
```

The request body as following.

```
{ 
    "__metadata":{ 
        "type":"SP.Folder"
    },
    "ServerRelativeUrl":"Shared Documents/buddhika-test-folder-03"
}
```

**Example code**:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFormDigest() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    });
}

function createFolderTest() {
    var documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents";
    var folderName="buddhika-test-folder-03";
    if(folderName!=""){
        createfolder(documentLibraryName,folderName).done(function (data) {
            console.log('Folder creted succesfully');
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });     
    }
    return true;
}
function createfolder(documentLibraryName,folderName){

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/folders";
    return getFormDigest().then(function (data) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            type: "POST",           
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data:JSON.stringify({'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': documentLibraryName+'/'+folderName}),
            headers: {
                "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",           
                "X-RequestDigest":data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
            } 
        });
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="createFolderTest()" value="Create Folder"/>
```

Comment: when I use above rest point I get 403 forbidden error. what could be the reason for that ?